# Visual studio fails to vectorise

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I tried to compile the following in VS2013

```
template <class T>
void assignment(T* result, size_t sz, const T x)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    result[i] = x;
}
```

and the compiler failed to vectorised the code with the following message.

```
info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1104'
```

while the following code is fine

```
void discountFactor(double* result, const double* r, double t, size_t sz)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    result[i] = -r[i] * t;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    result[i] = exp(result[i]);
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what is the cause of 1104?

Comment: All the error codes are explained on this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/05/22/auto-vectorizer-in-visual-studio-11-did-it-work.aspx) (in your case: *1104 - Loop body includes scalar variables*). Or was there something more you wanted?

Comment: Here is some more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658585.aspx#BKMK_ReasonCode110x

Comment: In the working example you have two arrays: result and r. In the example that doesn't work, you have an array and a scalar. 1104 is emitted when the scalar cannot be expanded as a vector. What is type T?

Comment: I did look at the msdn page, which explains it got to do with a scalar variable.  However, in my second example, t is a scalar variable too.  I can't see why the second one works.

T can be double or float.

Comment: @user4148224 can you provide a simple code snippet and the compiler options you're using to recreate the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, these types of optimizations are pretty well documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658585.aspx#BKMK_ReasonCode110x). In fact, there's a pretty good example there. Here's the snippet:

```
int code_1104(int *A, int *B)
{
    // When it vectorizes a loop, the compiler must 'expand' scalar
    // variables to a vector size such that they can fit in
    // vector registers. Code 1104 is emitted when the compiler
    // cannot 'expand' such scalars.

    // In this example, we try to 'expand' x to be used in the 
    // vectorized loop. However, there is a use of 'x' 
    // beyond the loop body, which prohibits this expansion.

    // To resolve this, try to limit scalars to be used only in
    // the loop body and not beyond, and try to keep their types
    // consistent with the loop types.

    int x;
    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
    {
        x = B[i];
        A[i] = A[i] + x;
    }

    return x;
}
```

My explanation (to be honest, they're just guesses):
The second example works because `result` is of a primitive datatype (`double *`) and can easily be modified even though it's outside of the loop's scope.

The example tells in its comment that...

```
// When it vectorizes a loop, the compiler must 'expand' scalar
// variables to a vector size such that they can fit in
// vector registers.
```

Depending on how you're calling your templated function `assignment`, your `T` in the first example might be **anything**. Included a type that does not fit in a register. Therefore I assume the compiler cannot automatically vectorize your `for`-loop.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything for me. What can the compiler not do and why exactly again? The sample compiles just fine at [ideone](http://ideone.com/uamM4e) (I actually tried to get better error or warning messages, but none were shown).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I mentioned I tried it with a different compiler, and it just goes well. Is it an actual disability of VS2013? And to cite from OP's comment: _" `T` can be `double` or `float`. "_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes, as the MSDN documentation clearly informs us.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I love how they proof themselves to provide a crappy compiler ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the compiler being able to make use of hardware features is a nice to have. I don't think visual studio is a "crappy compiler" just because it don't parallelize/vectorize code in every circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't do a good job determining which variables are used as read-only. You have to make sure the vectorized loops use const copies of local variables. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

void doIt(double* src, double* dst, double factor, int sz) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) { // loop vectorized
        dst[i] += src[i] * factor;
    }
}

int main() {
    static const int SZ = 1024;
    double sum = 0.0;
    double factor;
    double initial;
    double source[SZ];
    double destination[SZ];

    cin >> factor;
    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i) { // 22, reason 1200, data dependency expected
        cin >> source[i];
    }
    cin >> initial;

    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i) {  // 27, reason 1104
        destination[i] += source[i] * factor;
    }

    doIt(source, destination, factor, SZ); // 31, no problem

    return 0;
}
```

Here the loop in `doIt` is vectorized by the compiler, yet the same loop in `main` isn't.

**Why?**

Because `factor` is not a const variable and in the loop starting on line 27 it could be modified (even though it clearly isn't).

**Why doesn't `doIt` cause problems?**

Because factor is passed by value and not by reference.

**The fix?**

Make factor a const variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

void doIt(double* src, double* dst, double factor, int sz) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) { // loop vectorized
        dst[i] += src[i] * factor;
    }
}

double GetFactor() {
    double ret;
    cin >> ret;
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    static const int SZ = 1024;
    double sum = 0.0;
    const double factor = GetFactor();
    double initial;
    double source[SZ];
    double destination[SZ];

    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i) { // 22, reason 1200, data dependency expected
        cin >> source[i];
    }
    cin >> initial;

    for (int i = 0, mysz=SZ; i < mysz; ++i) {  // no problem
        destination[i] += source[i] * factor;
    }

    doIt(source, destination, factor, SZ); // no problem

    return 0;
}
```

**Great but what does this have to do with me?**

I suspect the template function you have is getting inlined and is essentially the same as the loop on line 27 in the first example. Try to change the variable `x` passed to the template function like follows:

old:

```
assignment(bob, sz, x);
```

new:

```
const double copyx = x;
assignment(bob, sz, copyx);
```